# Change OneDrive media player default

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, windows-media-player

I recently starting using OneDrive under my MS 365 subscription to backup files. Once it synced the files I noticed a problem with my PowerPoint files with links to videos. When opening these links from Slideshow mode now, the video opens with the OneDrive media player and you must use an additional step of manually playing the video. Prior to this Windows Media player just automatically started the video. Is it possible to auto start the video from this OneDrive Player or change the default for the media player back to the Windows Media Player?